# Choose a new random integer each time a function is called?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The section of code is:

```
originalpipey = random.randint(0, 500)
pipey = 0 - originalpipey
twopipey = pipey + 650

def spawnpipe(originalpipey, pipey, twopipey):
    screen.blit(pipe,(pipex, 0 - originalpipey))
    screen.blit(pipe2,(pipex, twopipey))
```

The original pipe y is how far down the page I want the pipe to be. The final pipe y is then 0 minus that, so that it goes above the screen and then goes that far down (I worked it out). The two pipe y is the second pipe y, basically just the original one add 650, which creates a 100 pixel gap between the two because I made the pipe png in photoshop 550 pixels tall.

I am making a Flappy Bird type game and this code is to make the Y size of the pipe. Whenever I use the function like this, it is the same size. However, if I put the random integer into the function, to make a new size, it just constantly changes the size. Is there any way to pick a new size each time is is repeated? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To have a new random integer every time a function is called call `randint` inside the function.

```
def myfunc():
    r = random.randint(0, 500)  # R is set every time function is called
```